# Is it advisable to make common request params, custom http headers?

Tags: rest, http, api-design

I am building a JSON http API (not necessarily REST) and every endpoint in it needs to take 2-3 common parameters. I was wondering if it would be better to move these common params to the header so that the request body can have only the parameters specific to the endpoint. Or is it better to keep them in the request body.

Is there any standard ways to do this or any common alternative methods?

Comment: Why do noy you couple that common parameters within a class and then send it in every request? Basic inheritance

Comment: Yes, that is possible, and would be one way to implement it. But the question is whether all requests "should" carry the common params in the first place.